# how to skip Show Inbox and selecting match in google play service turn based prime 31 plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, prime31

Following is log from android device (Samsung Galaxy Tab 2), which
performs good.

Steps are as follows taketurn ---->  then its UI
   state changes to `AuthenticatedWithNoMatchLoaded` ------> other
   player on another device (Samsung Galaxy Grand)  takes turn ------->
   state of this(i.e. samsung galexy tab 2 ) UI changes to
   `AuthenticatedWithActiveMatch` without going through 'show inbox' and
   'match selection'.

This is how I supposed that it should work.

But for other devices (Samsung Galaxy Grand) after taketurn, the state
   changes to `AuthenticatedWithNoMatchLoaded`, then it is not
   switching its state to `AuthenticatedWithActiveMatch` directly when
   other players turn is done. To check its turn have to go through
   'show inbox'-----------> then select match (here it is showing 'Its
   your turn')-----------> then take turn.

I have added a log for the device ( samsung galexy tab 2 ) behaving as
   per our scenario.

Please tell me what should I do to take response others turn, by
   avoiding the steps of show inbox and match selection. I am trying a
   lot but may be I am doing to wrong please let me know.

I have done this to restore the match-